How to hide the + cursor when the canvas is hovered in fabric.js?
I use fabric.js for drawing, when the drawing mode is true the cursor becomes a plus sign (+), I just want this + to be hidden because I add a circle to indicate the brush size.
I tried to hide the cursor of the canvas element but it has no effect.
